# How handle 'null' values in a json search

Tags: javascript, jquery

still new to JavaScript, I am searching for numbers in my JSON, but the JSON has a lot of null values. How can I ignore the null values in my search?

```
$.each(geojson.features, function (i, v) {
    if (v.properties.code.toString().search((/2/i)) != -1) {
        Count++;
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What does key `code` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
 if (v.properties.code && v.properties.code.toString().search((/2/i)) != -1) {
            Count++;
        }
```

first check value is not null and then search the string